# mocking creation of an array with powermock java

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I would like to write a test for the following function in java.i want to mocking the creation of the array.

```
public File[] myFunc()
{  

 File[] array = new File[2];

 return array;

}
```

i have wrote the following test using powermock java:

```
@Test

public void test1()
{

 File f1 = createMock(File.class);

 File[] files = new File[]{f1};

 expectNew(File[].class).andReturn(fArray);

 replayAll();

 File[] res = myclass.myFunc();

 verifyAll();

assertEquals(f1, res[0]);

}
```

it throws an exception with the following message:
`org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException: No constructor found in class java.io.file with parameter types:<none>`

Answer (score 0):

The exception already says it: you attempt to create a File instance without specifying constructor arguments but there is no constructor without parameters for the class java.io.File. The stack trace of the exception will tell you the code location of your attempt. I guess, its `File f1 = createMock(File.class);`. Check the powermock documentation for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to me to mock the creation of this array since there are no values in it. A much more concise test would be this:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    File[] result = myclass.myFunc();
    assertEquals(2, result.length);
    for (File f : result) {
        assertNull(f);
    }
}
```